# Auto forwarding emails in Gmail

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

I have set up a new Gmail address and I have put several addresses in for any incoming emails to be forwarded to automatically. My problem is that it only seems to be selecting the top email address, and not auto forwarding to them all.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Selecting another email address other than the top email address is possible:

[image]

To forward to several e-mail addresses, use POP.